# How do you use an assert statement to confirm the type of a python3 set

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, set, assert

How do I ensure that the parameters to this function must be of the `set` type?

I tried using the `isinstance` method placed in an assert statement to validate that the remaining and the used parmeters are set types only, but this failed.

```
def listAllSubset(remaining = set(), used = set()):
    assert(isinstance(remaining, set))
    assert(isinstance(used, set))

    if (len(remaining) == 0):
        print(used)
    else:
        element = remaining.pop()
        listAllSubset(remaining, used)
        listAllSubset(remaining, used.add(element))
```

I would like to see how to ensure that the `remaining` and `used` parameters are sets only.

Answer (score 0):

Not an efficient way, but a tricky way:

```
def listAllSubset(remaining = set(), used = set()):
    remaining.discard
    used.discard
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the `isinstance` is Authoritative, the point is in your last line of the code,

this is code

```py
def listAllSubset(remaining = set(), used = set()):
    assert(isinstance(remaining, set))
    assert(isinstance(used, set))

    if (len(remaining) == 0):
        print(used)
    else:
        element = remaining.pop()    # OK: element will be None
        listAllSubset(remaining, used)   # OK: remaining == used == set() 
        listAllSubset(remaining, used.add(element))    # Error: used.add(element) will return None, and the None will give to keyword argument "used", then "assert" will raise a AssertionError.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listAllSubset()
```

ok, 
Last line code `listAllSubset(remaining, used.add(element))` as equal `listAllSubset(set(), None`),
then `assert(isinstance(used, set))` will raise a AssertionError

---

### just look this code

```
used = set()
flag = used.add('_')
print(flag)    # print value of flag
```

> None

---

## changed

I change the code, mybe it can meet your needs,

```
def listAllSubset(remaining = set(), used = set()):
    assert(isinstance(remaining, set))
    assert(isinstance(used, set))

    if (len(remaining) == 0):
        print(used)
    else:
        element = remaining.pop()
        listAllSubset(remaining, used)
        used.add(element)
        listAllSubset(remaining, used)
```

please forgive me for my bad English, English is so hard!!